# How do I plot a single point in globejs()?

Tags: r

This is my first question here so sorry if I do something wrong. Just as the question says i want to show one single point in my 3D Globe using globejs() in R. I am creating a page with dashboard(), and inside the box(), i use leaflet and globejs() from package threejs. I´ve created two numericInput(), one for lat and one for long but it refuses to work. I have tried so many ways but doesn´t work. Somehow arcs works just fine in the data.frame I created, this is how is now, the basic way:

```
output$distPlot <- renderGlobe({
    ja<-c(input$arclat,input$arclong,input$arclat2,input$arclong2);
     m<-data.frame(matrix(ja,ncol=4,nrow=1));
      globejs(bg="white",lat=input$lat,long=input$long,value=45,arcs=m,arcsColor = "#99aaff", atmosphere = input$icon, arcsHeight = 0.1,arcsOpacity = 1 )
})
```

I hope you understood my problem. Help please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `globejs`.  Which package is that from?

Comment: I think is from threejs

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that

Comment: Done, hope I can find the answer

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general, it's best to provide a reproducible example which one can copy-paste-run (and experiment with). This will increase your chances of getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could plot a point:

```
library(shiny)
library(threejs)
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('long', 'longitude', 13.40),
    numericInput('lat', 'latitude', 52.52),
    globeOutput('plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderGlobe({
      globejs(
        lat=c(NA, input$lat), 
        long=c(NA, input$long), 
        pointsize=5,
        value=100)
    })
  }
)
runApp(app, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

[image]

It seems as if `globejs` needs a vector of at least length 2 in borth arguments `lat` and `long` - maybe a bug?

Comment: It works just fine, i would never have imagined. Really thank you.

Comment: @MediotakuTomas You're welcome. Feel free to check the answer, if it solved your problem. I also filed the issue [here](https://github.com/bwlewis/rthreejs/issues/64).